# Create dns zone records with php

Tags: php, cname, mx-record

I want to create a site like .co.cc but you.mydomain.net.  I can't seem to make it work.  I would ideally like to make a CNAME (and an MX record) when a user submits a form with the desired CNAME (I will tell them how to do that) and the sub domain they want.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: So basically you want to run your own DNS server? I would see the answer below by AlfaTeK. If it isn't, then explain more.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you really want but check this:
http://mysql-bind.sourceforge.net/